Implement video playback using NodeJS, FFMPEG and HLS.JS
I have RTSP stream coming from camera, which is converted to fragmented mp4 using FFMPEG. It is stored in a folder. Also manifest.m3u8 file is created using FFMPEG.
I am using Hls.js player on frontend for playing the video, also using a time slider for seeking forward and backward according to timestamp on time slider. Need to dynamically generate moov file.
My question is how do I implement above scenario on backend using NodeJS?
I'm new to Video domain so please help. Thanks in advance.
expected result should be when a user clicks on time slider on a specific timestamp, server needs to create a moov file as a start file segment using video metadata, hen client starts to download the moov file for preparing playback video. After that, the client download the actual fragmented video files to playback, the moov and fragmented file list should be defined in hls manifest file

Node.js doesn't have anything to do with it.  FFmpeg does the work for you.  You're using HLS... it can be served by any normal web server, which is the whole purpose of that protocol.  Can you show your FFmpeg command line?  You can adjust it to keep more items around in the manifest.  Also show your HLS.js player config.
